# Translating Double Verbs

Tags: traducción

How would the following two verb sentences be translating:

> The team started to get sad after getting scored on.

I have been looking online using translators and have not found a common answer for these types of translations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating from English is not that easy since we mostly invoke the subjunctive mood mostly everytime.

> 1. El equipo empezó a **ponerse triste** después de que les anotaran.
> 2. ... a **entristecerse** después de que les anotaran.

Often, *get + adjective* invokes *ponerse + adjetivo*.

Note if we don't consider it a hypothetical situation, we use the indicative *anotaron* instead of *anotaran.*

Answer (score 1):

There could be several translations. Here some alternatives.

> El equipo comenzó a estar/ponerse triste después de que les anotaran
>
> La moral del equipo bajó después de que les anotaran.